# Transitive dependency management for Matlab

Tags: matlab, dependency-management

Is there a **transitive** dependency management solution for matlab?
Manageable items are directories containing *.m files.
Transitivity means

- Functions in directory A depend on functions in directory B
- Functions in directory B depend on functions in directory C
- Then A also depends on C

Dependencies will be explicitly declared by the modeler.

The solution must be able to manage dependencies

- in a Matlab session, i.e. managing the path
- for the command-line compiler mcc (via the -I option)

As such the solution should not rely on depfun().

So far, we did not find any existing solution or tooling. Neither from Mathworks nor on FileExchange.

As a next step, we would be looking into rolling our own solution. Preferably using some scripting language we can deploy inside AND outside of Matlab.

Comment: Are you looking to create a [linked list](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_oop/example--implementing-linked-lists.html)?

Comment: This is no coding question. The tool may use some sort of referencing, internally.

Comment: Questions asking SO to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem  and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: While this question could sound off-topic for the reason Roney Michael gave, I'm think this question has value in the scope of our community. Just as Maven handles dependencies for Java, what is the solution in Matlab?

Comment: Right, Maven for Matlab, not that I like Maven so much :)